# Get random seed in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, random-seed, rcpparmadillo

I need to minimize a function, let's say `f(theta)`. In  `f(theta)`, I draw VERY BIG matrices from a given distribution. So, throughout the optimization process, I have to keep the same matrices. However, as the matrices are too big, I cannot save them. Thus, for every value of `theta`, I decide to find a way to draw the same matrices. This can be done if I define a seed, which will be used each time the function is called. But I do not want the user to set the seed, I need the software to get the current seed and then use that seed for every new value of `theta`.

This a simplify example if I use R.

```
f <- function(theta, SEED) {
  .Random.seed <- SEED
  # I simplify the problem, I replace the big matrices by a small vector
  return(sum((rnorm(10) - theta)^2))
}

optim(par = 0, fn = f, method = "Brent", lower = -1, upper = 1, SEED = .Random.seed)
```

`.Random.seed` allows me to get a seed which will be used in `f`. This ensures that, during the optimization, `rnorm(10)` will not be changed although it is not saved. How can I construct a similar function using `Rcpp`?

Answer (score 2):

Rcpp already deal with this for you, and that is (amply) documented.  To wit:

```
> set.seed(42)
> rnorm(3)
[1]  1.370958 -0.564698  0.363128
> rnorm(3)
[1]  0.632863  0.404268 -0.106125
> Rcpp::cppFunction("Rcpp::NumericVector myrn(int n) {return Rcpp::rnorm(3);}")
> myrn(3)   # __not reseeded, different__
[1]  1.511522 -0.094659  2.018424
> set.seed(42)
> myrn(3)   # reseeded, same as above from R
[1]  1.370958 -0.564698  0.363128
> myrn(3)   # ditto
[1]  0.632863  0.404268 -0.106125
>
```

After you call the function you are supposed to call, `set.seed()`, you get *identical draws* in both R and C++.  So call a seed before calling your function and all is well.

Comment: Thank you Dirk. But this does not fix the issue. I have to set the seed in the function because the function will be called many times by optim. So if I set the seed before, I will get different values for rnorm when the function will be called several times in optim. To find the minimum, optim will call the function for several values of theta. I need draws rnorm() to be identical when f will be called for several values of theta.

Comment: The C API for R itself does _not_ offer a call from C to set the seed. So you are shooting the messenger.  An additional two minutes with the documentation (or examples) for `Rcpp::Function()` will make you realize that this is a non-issue as you can call an R function from C(++) if you really must.  But _maybe_ you should simply rethink your problem and for example use a _different RNG_ that you control entirely from C++ and that is independent of R. It all depends, only you can decide, and we are *not* holding any tools away from you.